# How to extract specific part of html page using c# code

Tags: c#, html

I have a webpage. I want to extract a specific part of the page but not full page. For example, from 4 inch left, 4 inch right, from top of website page. Please guide me how to achieve this. Here is my code.

```
   public string GetWebSiteContents(string url)
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        // Get the stream from the returned web response
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        string strLine;
        // Read the stream a line at a time and place each one into the stringbuilder
        while ((strLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Ignore blank lines
            if (strLine.Length > 0) sb.Append(strLine);
        }
        sr.Close();
        textBox1.Text = sb.ToString(); 
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This code works fine, but extracts the full page and it takes so much time.

Comment: You can not just specify the offset in inches - if you know the HTML page structure and want to get a specific element you'll have a better chance to get answered.

Comment: While you can extract parts of the DOM pretty easily, I don't think you can easily specify what part to visually take. You'd need to create a browser (or use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) component from Win Forms), get it to render a screenshot, then crop it down. Sounds like a whole lot of work though: are you sure you really need to do this? What is the desired goal, where and how will this be used?

Comment: actuly i m working on a project to get forex rate from a website.here is site link https://www.instaforex.com/

Answer (score 0):

One easy way of achieving what you are trying to do is to use a tool such as Selenium to automate a real browser and then using HTML tags, you can retrieve whatever information is saved, for a example in the left div or table on the page. Check out [this example](http://scraping.pro/example-of-scraping-with-selenium-webdriver-in-csharp/) for a tutorial on Selenium.